# No system command when using mysql from cli

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

Attempting to change directories, view directory contents, etc., but for some reason I don't have the system command to use the command line once I run mysql.  These are the options I get:

```
List of all MySQL commands:
Note that all text commands must be first on line and end with ';'
?         (\?) Synonym for `help'.
clear     (\c) Clear the current input statement.
connect   (\r) Reconnect to the server. Optional arguments are db and host.
delimiter (\d) Set statement delimiter.
ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
exit      (\q) Exit mysql. Same as quit.
go        (\g) Send command to mysql server.
help      (\h) Display this help.
notee     (\t) Don't write into outfile.
print     (\p) Print current command.
prompt    (\R) Change your mysql prompt.
quit      (\q) Quit mysql.
rehash    (\#) Rebuild completion hash.
source    (\.) Execute an SQL script file. Takes a file name as an argument.
status    (\s) Get status information from the server.
tee       (\T) Set outfile [to_outfile]. Append everything into given outfile.
use       (\u) Use another database. Takes database name as argument.
charset   (\C) Switch to another charset. Might be needed for processing binlog
with multi-byte charsets.
warnings  (\W) Show warnings after every statement.
nowarning (\w) Don't show warnings after every statement.
```

Any ideas what could cause this?  It seems to be possible using windows (using \!).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the MySQL documentation, the MySQL system command works only in Unix and therefore not in Windows:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html